# Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The configuration parameter "formElement" is a required for "custom_attribute" field

Tags: error, magento-2.1

I have created and uninstall an attribute for product. After deleting it completely, when I click on "ADD PRODUCT", the above error is coming.

Comment: Add code of install script

Comment: I checked there was permission issue  and owner name issue ,after deleting var folder,

Answer (score 8):

Go to database `eav_attribute` table

find your attribute row check frontend_input column there is null value in your attribute fill it with appropriate value